# assign command output to variable

Tags: linux, bash

I'm cloning lots of virtual machines, and I need to edit **/etc/hostname** and replace old hostname with a new one.

then I would have to run

```
hostname new-server-name
```

and log out of the ssd session and login again.

I'm trying to make my job easier by doing this

```
echo "new-server-name" > /etc/hostname
```

if there is a way to assign the value to **/etc/hostname** to host command? Something like

```
cat /etc/hostname | hostname
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
hostname $(cat /etc/hostname)
```

And don't forget to edit `/etc/hosts` to reflect the correct host name as well.

Comment: For the record, this feature is called [*command substitution*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).